# Aplicação em 3 camadas X MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estava conversando com um colega de faculdade e ele comentou algo à respeito de [aplicação em 3 camadas](https://imasters.com.br/dotnet/aplicacao-em-3-camadas-com-asp-net-c), pensei em algo parecido com *MVC* e pesquisando mais um pouco, realmente essa aplicação em 3 camadas se parece com *MVC* em alguns conceitos.

Visto que:

**MVC**

- Model (Dados)
- View(interface)
- Controller(Negócio)

**3 camadas**

- UI(Interface)
- BLL(Negócio)
- DAL(Dados)

Visto isso me retornou algumas dúvidas:

Qual a real diferença de cada, visto que ambas separam o projeto de forma que fique mais coeso e fácil de trabalhar ?

Quais são as particularidades que essa aplicação de 3 camadas tem?

Um aplicação criada em MVC, caso fosse criada em 3 camadas teria o mesmo resultado ?